# How to force `condition-case` to activate the debugger

Tags: debug

Often times I need to debug code wrapped in the BODYFORM of `condition-case`; however, the debugger is suppressed even though I have `debug-on-error` set to `t`.  The doc-string states that we can add `debug` to the list of handlers, but I didn't find a good example by Googling of how this might be accomplished.  Modifying the code of something that I am trying to debug to add a handler seems rather inefficient.

Is there an approach to force `condition-case` to always generate a debugging message without modifying the section of code that I am trying to debug?  If not, then an explanation why along with a sample of how to use `debug` as a handler would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Have you tried using `condition-case-unless-debug` instead of `condition-case`?

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for the suggestion -- I'll give that a try this morning.

Comment: FYI, setting `debug-on-signal` can be useful for this too (although it's sometimes a bit too much).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `condition-case-unless-debug` instead of `condition-case`.

You should be able to `M-x debug-on-entry` either `foo` or `bar` in this context:

```
(defun foo ()
  (condition-case-unless-debug nil
      (bar)
    (error nil)))

(defun bar ()
  (message "Cuckoo!")
  (pp-eval-expression '(cons 42 49)))
```

Note that `condition-case-unless-debug` just does this:

```
(macroexpand '(condition-case-unless-debug nil (bar) (error nil)))
```

gives

```
(condition-case nil
    (bar)
  ((debug error)
   nil))
```